# SQL Number of Customer 1st appointment

Tags: sql

I have a homework, but thinking my answer is not right.

---

**Question**: Find daily new customers who made their 1st appointment in July 2007?

- Table 1.A - order_item : This table shows transaction at order level on a daily basis
- Table 1.B - first_appointment : This table shows the first appointment date of each customer (1 person/1 log)

Key: customer_id

Fields:
order_item.create_datetime is when customers book their appointment
first_appointment.result_first_appointment_time is when customers book their first appointment

---

I come up with something like this, but I'm pretty sure that it is not a correct answer.

```
SELECT 
    DATE(order_item.create_datetime) AS appointment_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT oi.customer_id) AS new_customers
FROM 
    order_item
JOIN 
    first_appointment ON order_item.customer_id = first_purchase.customer_id
WHERE 
    DATE(order_item.create_datetime) BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-30'
GROUP BY 
    DATE(order_item.create_datetime);
```

Expected result:

| create_date | num_of_first_appointment_customers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 | nnnn |
| 2022-07-02 | nnnn |

Comment: Haven't you tried your query? The only way to learn SQL is practice, practice. practice.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: first_appointment is a very strange table. Or is it a view?

Comment: @jarlh I just copied the text file for the question and pasted it here. So yeah it might be columns instead. I got a rough idea that I should join 2 tables together, but I'm not sure about my approach here.

Comment: Looks like a good start, I'd try and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question with necessary information so we can help you. Do take care to include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and to [tag your RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms). And as jarlh mentioned first step is trying query you wrote. :)

Comment: July has 31 days. Also, you mention 2007 as the year, but your query is 2021.

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. `DATE` is not a standard SQL function, and `'2021-07-01'` is not a standard SQL date literal, but a string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table containing the first appointment per customer along with the date. You want to find first appointments in July 2007. So, everything you need is already in that table.

Why then do you join all orders placed by the same customer to their first order? That doesn't seem to make sense.

According to the description, this should be the query you want:

```
SELECT
  DATE(result_first_appointment_time) AS appointment_date,
  COUNT(*) AS new_customers
FROM first_appointment
WHERE result_first_appointment_time >= DATE '2007-07-01'
  AND result_first_appointment_time <  DATE '2007-08-01'
GROUP BY DATE(result_first_appointment_time)
ORDER BY DATE(result_first_appointment_time);
```